# Wordcount Program for Apache PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have been given a task to create a wordcount program in Python Spark. I am supposed to count the number of words starting with each alphabet.

Here's the code I have written but I can't seem to get the result. Could anyone help me with troubleshooting?

in.txt content:
people are not as beautiful as they look, 
as they walk or as they talk. 
they are only as beautiful  as they love, 
as they care as they share.

```
import re
import sys
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
inRDD = sc.textFile("in.txt")
words = inRDD.flatMap(lambda l: re.split(" ",l))
LetterCount = words.map(lambda s : (s[0],1))
result = LetterCount.reduceByKey(lambda n1, n2 : n1 + n2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is OK. 
Just need to add the `collect` at the end :

```
result.collect()  

[('s', 1),
 ('l', 2),
 ('a', 10),
 ('n', 1),
 ('t', 8),
 ('c', 1),
 ('p', 1),
 ('b', 2),
 ('w', 1),
 ('o', 2)]
```

And you can replace

```
import re
words = inRDD.flatMap(lambda l: re.split(" ",l))
```

with

```
words = inRDD.flatMap(str.split)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Wordcount Program for Apache PySpark using sparkSQL function  Easiest way**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

wordsDF = spark.read.text("path/log.txt")
df = wordsDF.withColumn('wordCount', f.size(f.split(f.col('value'), ' ')))
df.createOrReplaceTempView("wc")
df2 = spark.sql("SELECT SUM(wordCount) as Total FROM wc").show()


+-----+
|Total|
+-----+
|  147|
+-----+
```